# How do I increase significant digits in Grapher?

Tags: macos, grapher

How do I increase the significant digits in Grapher?

Answer (score 4):

All the numbers settings can be found via **Grapher → Preferences → Numbers**.

[image]

You can set the “Notation” setting to “Engineering” to display numbers as `123,4568e3` (7 significant digits) instead of `1,2346e5` (5 significant digits).

Perhaps the “Number of Decimals” setting is of interest, too.